# Excel VBA For Loop - condition not being satisfied

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA coding so please bear with me.

The aim of the subroutine below is to go through a range of cells which I have specified and copy and paste them elsewhere if they meet the following criteria:

1. TankerCell (cell D3) is not empty
2. TankerCell's value is numeric

If not, I want it to run the `del` macro, which will delete the row to which `TankerCell` belongs if it doesn't meet the above criteria.

I have declared the other subroutines `CopyandPaste`, `del` and `IncrementDate` on a seperate module.

`CopyandPaste` is simply a macro that copies and pastes a predefined selection to a predefined cell *and then deletes the initial range (from which data was copied)*, `IncrementDate` simply adds one day to the previous date and `del` deletes a predefined selection from the table being copied.

So far, the subroutine copies and pastes all the items across to the new table I have set up...It doesn't delete any data that it should delete.

Can you spot why this is happening?

```
Sub BulkCandP()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LoopMax As Range, TankerCell As Range
    Dim NumericCheck As Boolean, EmptyCheck As Boolean

    Set LoopMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N3")
    Set TankerCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")
    NumericCheck = IsNumeric(TankerCell.Value) 'check if cell data is a number
    EmptyCheck = IsEmpty(TankerCell.Value) 'check if cell data is present


    For i = 1 To LoopMax.Value 'for all rows for the date range
        If i = 1 Then
            Call CopyAndPaste
            Call IncrementDate 'for first entry, increment date on table by 1
        ElseIf i > 1 Then
            If (NumericCheck = False Or EmptyCheck = True) Then
                Call del
            Else
                Call CopyAndPaste 'bulk copy and paste values
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: `bare with me.` [NO!](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bare) Count me out :P

Comment: @SiddharthRout so edit the question to correct it :)

Comment: @nekomatic: I am already doing it ;)

Comment: @nekomatic "The humor is slowly dying in Excel forum" :(

Comment: To the questioner: I don't see why your `if..then` structure is inside the `for..next` loop. From your description, you either want to do the copy and paste operations (if `TankerCell` contains a number) or you want to do the delete operation which should only happen once. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Typo! sorry!

Comment: @nekomatic indeed you have the right of it, but I want to perform the task a set number of times (the number is in LoopMax). Hence the if statement inside the for loop. Does that make sense?

Comment: In ref to your last comment: Your code will run only `LoopMax.value` times. So why the need for those checks?

Comment: Still don't understand, sorry. The code you have posted checks whether `TankerCell` meets your criteria, then it calls `CopyAndPaste` and then `IncrementDate`, then it either calls `CopyAndPaste` a further (LoopMax - 1) times, or it calls `del` (LoopMax - 1) times. Is that what you're actually trying to do - in the delete case, do you actually want to delete (LoopMax - 1) rows?

Comment: @nekomatic I now see the problem, but not how to fix it! After the i=1 loop, I want it to check what value TankerCell has. If it's empty or non-numeric, I want to run "del". If it isn't, I want to run "CopyandPaste". I want this to be the logic for the (TankerCell-1) loops. I also made an edit to the description of "CopyandPaste" in my question as I realise now that that was a key part of the macro...apologies for that!

Comment: Will the first calls to `CopyAndPaste` and `IncrementDate` affect the value of `TankerCell`? If so, you need to move those calls to before the code where you check the value of `TankerCell`. If that doesn't solve your problem then I think you need to (a) verify with some simple test data that `CopyAndPaste` and `del` actually take the action you expect them to, and (b) set some breakpoints in your code and step through it to check that the variables are taking the values you expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i As Integer
Dim LoopMax As Range, TankerCell As Range
Dim NumericCheck As Boolean, EmptyCheck As Boolean

Set LoopMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N3")
Set TankerCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")

'~~> Run it at least once
Call CopyAndPaste
Call IncrementDate

For i = 1 To (LoopMax.Value - 1)
    NumericCheck = IsNumeric(TankerCell.Value) 'check if cell data is a number
    EmptyCheck = IsEmpty(TankerCell.Value) 'check if cell data is present

    If (NumericCheck = False Or EmptyCheck = True) Then
        Call del
    Else
        Call CopyAndPaste 'bulk copy and paste values
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: It still appears to copy and paste rows if TankerCell is empty. The problem (I think!) is that it doesn't perform the checks on TankerCell on each iteration of "i" as I want it to...although it should be doing that...

Comment: Yes it will .. at least once as I have kept it outside the loop. Is your tanker cell changing after every loop?

Comment: It is indeed...I thought the "For" loop would take care of that?

Comment: No it won't :) I have updated the code. Now test it. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what do you mean by "refresh the page"? I tried the above code and it still pastes the blanks across...

Comment: Press F5 on this page. it will reload the page so that you can see the edited code

Comment: this gives me the following error when running: "object required", and points to the `NumericCheck = IsNumeric(TankerCell.Value)` part of the code. Any ideas why?

Comment: Umm No. That error would come if you have not declared what `TankerCell` is

Comment: done, and done :) had to make a couple of changes but the macro works like a charm now! thanks for everything :)